# Database Not closed error in android sqlite

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

My whole application is running fine but when I see the logcat i could see these error messages like database is not closed even after i closed the database with statement MyDBinstance.close(). Why are they coming again?,Are they harmful to my application?

```
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762): close() was never explicitly called on  database '/data/data/dlp.android.digichronicle/databases/widget.sqlite' 
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1943)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1007)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:962)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at dlp.android.digichronicle.DBHandandler.openDataBase(DBHandandler.java:117)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at dlp.android.digichronicle.inter.FetchingData(inter.java:95)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at dlp.android.digichronicle.inter.onCreate(inter.java:29)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 11-23 23:09:03.593: E/SQLiteDatabase(30762):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 11-23 23:09:03.752: I/dalvikvm(30762): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
 11-23 23:09:03.811: I/dalvikvm(30762): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 11-23 23:09:16.182: I/System.out(30762): got from accounts1.0exp1.0
 11-23 23:09:16.332: I/System.out(30762): Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]
```

Comment: Yes, you should to close all your datasets after used then. Use a try..finally block on each method where you use a sqlite dataset/cursor.

Comment: The rule is: every time you call `db = getWritableDatabase()` or `db = getReadableDatabase()` you **must** call `db.close()`. The logcat is stating that this hasn't happened despite your efforts, but it is impossible to give you specific advice without seeing any code.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do like this to make sure you always close the cursor:

```
Cursor c = null;
try   {

   c  = somehowCreateACursor();

} finally {

    if(c != null) {
        c.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I have another question now. how can use sum() of and BETWEEN in an sql query where between acts on dates

Comment: @user1848183 you can call db.rawQuery and pass to it your SQL string

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no need to close the database. Even after the fact that there will yield the above stated exceptions but it will never harm the app in any way.

Comment: You should **always** close your database when you are done using it to release the allocated memory and have a faster app.